# Maching N first characters in a regexp

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to check if the first N characters match a regexp. In this case 3 characters. Why nil in both cases?

```
irb(main):004:0> "abc" =~ /abcde{3}/
=> nil


irb(main):008:0> /abcde{3}/ =~ "abc"
=> nil
```

Comment: Seems like you are confusing the pattern with the string the pattern is being searched in. `/ell/` matches `"hello"` (there's an "ell" in "hello"), but `/hello/` doesn't match `"ell"` (there's no "hello" in "ell").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is trying for three occurrence of char **e** in both the statements but you don't have that. So, your regex could be like this,

```
"abcdeee" =~ /abcde{3}/
# => 0
/abcde{3}/ =~ 'abcdeee'
# => 0
```

So, I think you need to use the regex like below to match N chars,

```
'abcdee' =~ /[a-e]{3}/
# => 0
$&
# => "abc"
```

Please let me know if you need more on this.

Comment: What do you mean by "three occurrence[s] of char[actor] `c`"?

Comment: Three occurrence in the sense three time repetition of char c in the regex /abcde{3}/.

Comment: Where is char[acter] `c` repeated three times?

Answer (score 0):

One way to say it is that it is because the string `"abc"` is shorter than seven characters.

Answer (score 0):

You messed up regexp and the string. `/abcde{3}/` means `/abcdeee/`. What you need is:

```
"abcde"[0...3] =~ /\Aabc\z/
```

or just:

```
"abcde" =~ /\Aabc/
```

Comment: `"abcde"[3]` is `"d"`.

Comment: @sawa oh, yeah, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with following exp

```
/[abcde]{3}/
```